# Counting the number of rows in a specific worksheet

Tags: vba, excel

I launch the following code from workbook1, and want to count the number of rows in workbook2(wb.Name). Why does partII return the row count from workbook1?

```
Dim partII As String
Workbooks(wb.Name).Activate
Workbooks(wb.Name).Worksheets("sheet1").Select
partII = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
For Each myRecord In Workbooks(wb.Name).Worksheets("sheet1").Range("A1:A" & partII)
```

Comment: What do you mean by `"Workbook2"`? And why are you accessing your workbook through the `Workbooks` collection when you seemingly already have a workbook reference named `wb`?

Answer (score 1):

1. Avoid Activate and Select as much as possible
2. I repeat, avoid Activate and Select as much as possible
3. Your range refers to the active sheet, so it should be pulling wb.name / sheet 1.

Try the following simplified code:

```
with wb.worksheets("sheet1")
    partII = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row 

    For Each myRecord In .Range("A1:A" & partII)
        '...
    Next myRecord

end with
```

Comment: Will try.. btw, what is wrong with Activate and Select? without knowing any better, I wrote that in many of my spreadsheets.

Comment: Couple different things: 1. they slow things down tremendously (especially once you start selecting cells in loops, 2. they make it hard to track in macros where the object actually is, making complex procedures harder to maintain. There's probably a few others but those are the main ones that come to my mind.